# Replace words in Strings

Tags: java, string, replace, state

I have a on/off button that I want to change the value of a String, if the String contains `randomnessOn` it will change to `randomnessOff` and vice versa. I can't just override the String because it doesn't only contain the value of the state of the on/off button. I have tried this code.

```
if(command.equals(randFor) | command.equals(randBack) | command.equals(randButton)){
        if(option.contains("randomnessOf")){
            randomness = true;
            randState = "ON";
            randStateX = 975;
            randStateY = 245;
            option = option.replace("randomnesOff", "randomnessOn");
        }
        if(option.contains("randomnessOn")){
            randomness = false;
            randState = "OFF";
            randStateX = 970;
            randStateY = 245;
            option = option.replace("randomnesOn", "randomnessOff");
        }
        loadOptions();
    }
```

It will change the text of the `randState` String and change the position of the text but it wont replace the word in the `option` String, so how would I do to replace words in the String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It will change the text of the randState String and change the position of the text but it wont replace the word in the option String, so how would I do to replace words in the String?

Java Strings are immutable.   You can't change them.

This line:

```
    option = option.replace("randomnesOn", "randomnessOff");
```

is creating a new String based on the original value of `option` with the relevant characters replaced.  You now have to use this new string to update the GUI.  For example, you might need to call `setText(option)` on some Swing button or label object.

Remember that assigning a new value to `option` is only affecting that local variable.  It certainly won't and can't affect your GUI ... unless you *do something* to make that happen.

Comment: @vidit - I can see that.  But it is obviously not working for him.

Comment: @StephenC- I wrote it before your edit, will just delete the comment.

Answer (score 1):

You change the value references by the variable named "option".
Possibly, you have some GUI element (e.g. JButton) having its "Text" set to the original value of `option`. If you need to update the visual elelement (e.g. JButton), you have to do it explicitely, e.g. calling `myButton.setText(option)` (after you assign the new value to variable `option`).

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(option.contains("randomnessOf")){
               //....
                option = option.replace("randomnessOff", "randomnessOn");// 
              //randomnessOf with two `s`
            }
            if(option.contains("randomnessOn")){
               //....
                option = option.replace("randomnessOn", "randomnessOff");
               //the same as firtst you forgot one 's'
}
```